# CSS HTML Bootstrap layout issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a page with 2 full height columns. the left column is for a menu. The right section will hold a form. I'm trying to make this a responsive page by using Bootstrap. I have written the following code, but when I resize the window, the form content overflows into the left menu. I tried using Bootstrap grid, but then ended up using my own CSS. This still won't work.

I created a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/snehilw/8zrkcyyx/

My current layout looks like this:

```html
<div class="containerr">
  <div class="roww">
    <!-- Left Navigation Menu  -->
    <div class="coll-md-2 no-float">
      <div class="nav-side-menu">
        <div class="brand"> &nbsp</div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
        <div class="menu-list">
          <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i>Scenario Builder <span class="badge badge-right">3</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id= "addNewScenario">
              <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-lg"></i> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add New Scenario
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-lg"></i><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Save
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-lg"></i><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span> Test
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- FORM CONTENT -->
    <!-- End Form content-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Please advise on how to fix the form overflowing into the menu using Bootstrap or CSS.

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/snehilw/8zrkcyyx/

Comment: `class = row` instead of `roww `

Comment: yes i changed that to a custom css since bootsrap did not seem to work. the 'roww' clas is defined in the css if you look at the jsfiddle

Comment: I don't think you are using bootstrap properly. If you're resorting to "custom" classes to replace bootstrap classes like "roww" and "coll-md-2" then you need to re-think your approach.

Comment: yes i dont want to take that approach either, if you comment on what can i do with the fiddle to get this working with bootsrap, i have tried and tried...sigh...

Comment: Example: you are using a fixed width on the menu (yet using a class with a 15% width on it's container/parent). This is part of your problem. You could "fix" your overlap issue by adding a fixed width of 280px (the width of your menu currently) to the parent container: `<div class="coll-md-2 no-float" style="width:280px">` but I do not recommend this as a solution.

Comment: So you're trying to do something like this: http://www.bootply.com/69863

Comment: yes something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap Solution

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      html for menu
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      html for form
    </div>

 </div>    
</div>
```

also if you want it to stack on smaller devices you could use
col-sm-6 instead

Comment: i tried the above approach and the content still overflows into the left menu

Comment: did you remove the fixed widths in your css?

Comment: let bootstrap handle the widths, they got it down so you dont have to

Comment: i cleared everything else, and it seems to work. but now both the columns are at the center of the page with some padding on left and right. how do i move the menu to the leftmost end and let the form flow to the right side? i tried using this for the 2 rows: col-md-2 and col-md-10 but layout gets messed up for those again.. only col-6 works fine but they have padding to left and right

Comment: instead of container use container-fluid

Comment: that fixed the menu but the form still has some padding on the left..i did change it to fluid for the form;s container as well, the form i am using is on the jsfiddle

Comment: also be mindful of what size you are using col-md-2 is going to break on a medium sized device, so anything smaller than md is going to stack. you use col-sm-2 col-sm-10 or col-sm-4 col-sm-8 if you need more menu room.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79462/discussion-between-jhampac-and-rookie).

Comment: thanks a ton to review this and help me in the chat!!! really appreciate your patience and help....thank you so much!!!!! we debugged a few problems we ran into